# Can't open certain csv files using pandas while being written with pandas - CParserError

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I'm obtaining tweets to analyze, using [`tweepy`](http://tweepy.readthedocs.org/en/v3.5.0/) I'm writing the data to csv using:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['ID', 'ORIG', 'LAT', 'LONG', 'CITY', 'STATE', 'TIMESTAMP', 
                           'TWEET_ID', 'TWEET'])
"""Extracting tweet data using tweepy"""
df.loc[self.tweet_counter] = [user_id, 1, lat_long[1], lat_long[0], city, state, 
                             time_stamp, tweet_id, tweet_text]
df.to_csv('orig/{0}.csv'.format(tweet_date), mode='a', encoding='utf-8', header=False, 
          index=False)
```

Everything works fine up to here. After collecting data for a couple of days I'm doing some analysis, I open up the file as such:

```
for file in files:
    print(file)
    orig = pd.read_csv('orig\\'+file,names=['ID','ORIG','LAT','LONG','CITY','STATE','DATE',
                                            'TWEET_ID','TWEET'],
                        usecols=['CITY','STATE','DATE','TWEET_ID'],
                        encoding='utf-8')
```

`files` is the list of files in the current directory that I'm trying to analyze. There's about 14 files which I obtain the names using [`os`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/os.html) module.

**Error from opening the files**

```
2016-02-05.csv
2016-02-06.csv
2016-02-07.csv
2016-02-08.csv
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Leb/Desktop/Python/Houston/comparison.py", line 30, in <module>
    encoding='utf-8')
  File "C:\Program Files\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 498, in parser_f
    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 285, in _read
    return parser.read()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 747, in read
    ret = self._engine.read(nrows)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 1197, in read
    data = self._reader.read(nrows)
  File "pandas\parser.pyx", line 766, in pandas.parser.TextReader.read (pandas\parser.c:7988)
  File "pandas\parser.pyx", line 788, in pandas.parser.TextReader._read_low_memory (pandas\parser.c:8244)
  File "pandas\parser.pyx", line 842, in pandas.parser.TextReader._read_rows (pandas\parser.c:8970)
  File "pandas\parser.pyx", line 829, in pandas.parser.TextReader._tokenize_rows (pandas\parser.c:8838)
  File "pandas\parser.pyx", line 1833, in pandas.parser.raise_parser_error (pandas\parser.c:22649)
pandas.parser.CParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 1113330, saw 9
```

I have listed below 2 lines before and after 1113330 from `2016-02-08.csv`.

```
#line 1113328#    2371126254,0.0,,,Rancho Cucamonga,CA,2016-02-08 07:27:09,696596108840034304,@winnjinn I miss it with youu
#line 1113329#    747612104,0.0,,,Portland,OR,2016-02-08 07:27:09,696596108907184130,"When the term hasn't even started yet, but multiple profs have already emailed you homework that's due on the first day#welcometocollege"
#line 1113330#    954897794,0.0,,,Manteca,CA,2016-02-08 07:27:09,696596108504510464,FUCKKKKKKK 6th grade was all bad https://t.co/3fShejyPv6
#line 1113331#    608779746,0.0,,,San Marcos,TX,2016-02-08 07:27:09,696596109385314305,@keeshawnnnnn  https://t.co/g9r8AX7zMn
#line 1113332#    4729317440,0.0,,,Seattle,WA,2016-02-08 07:27:09,696596109876027392,".@tedcruz aka the Antichrist CAMPAIGN GUY JEFF ROE DID SAME DIRTY TRICK N 2010, SAID CANDDTE DROPPED OUT! DW
```

**Cause of the error**

The error arises from malformed data (i.e. extra delimiter). However, the data is written properly with `pandas` and there are no extra delimiters. A possible workaround is to add `error_bad_lines = False` as suggested [here](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/2886), but I can't ignore those lines, especially if there are no malformed data and I risk losing additional data that could be used in analysis.

How else can I address this issue?

Comment: I get EOF error when pasting your data into a file and reading into pandas. Then just `import csv` and `df = pd.read_csv('/path/to/filename.csv', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)`

Comment: I actually get : `EOF inside string starting at line 4` trying to parse just use those few lines

Comment: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/5500

Comment: The final line in your example is corrupt (missing end quote). Maybe that's a cut/paste error, I don't know, but if you are doing the scraping in parallel and multiple threads could be appending the same file, then you have a problem.

Comment: BTW, are you creating a dataframe just to add one row to a csv?

Comment: mkln: `quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE` causes other problems as there are qutoes throughout the file and this causes malformed data....
Padraic Cunningham: I don't get `EOF` error at all as the error is happening at random location in random files....
tdelaney: The analysis is happening days after data collection, so there's no multi-threading. The missing quote is indeed a copy/paste error.

Comment: I wasn't worried about clashes between collection and analysis. Assuming the csv is written during collection, the question is whether that is parallelized. If not, my worry of conflicting appends is not a problem. The interesting thing about @PadraicCunningham's link is that the corrupt line could be many lines above.

Comment: Why not store as HDF or something else?  CSV not generally the best way to store things if you can help it.

Comment: @tdelaney if I edit part of the line that's causing the problem it's no longer an issue. So the problem is with the line that's being reported by the error.